# HowTo make fish fins without hard-modeling (IE: one vertex at a time making RAT mesh)

Tags: modeling

I am wanting to make a sea serpent, and he needs a top fin. Thing is I am stumped as to how to make such a fin without doing about 30 RAT (right about there) operations, let alone produce geometrically "nice" results with realistic looking curves. I am perceiving a Subdivision Surface modifier, but is there a quicker way to create the base mesh?

I want something with obvious spines, and pulled down, thinner membranes between them. In real life this would look so much like a cloth draped over posts in a row I've considered doing that, but is there another way?
This is the serpent with SS modifier on it, the fin prototype as a separate object in edit mode. The main trouble here has been making skin between the spines but also making the spines end up thicker.
[image: What I have now]

Comment: hello, what have you tried? where are you now, currently in the process? What reference images are you working with that could be added to the question via [edit]? Please add more information to narrow the question scope, and clarity. Thanks

Comment: 1) A few things with "Skin" modifier. Maybe I'm just being lazy... 2) I have a "digiplastic" grey worm with little strings of vertices coming out of his back, barely resembling a fin in my opinion. 3) The drawing I made 3 days before I started the model :D

Comment: I feel like I've been getting not as good at asking questions. Help me, God.

Comment: Please add new information in the body of your question, there are many users that do not read comments, and it helps keep the site more organized if all information is contained the same way. Plus comments are not searchable by search engines, so their information is not very useful over time...

Comment: Again. Please add a reference image, or sketch of what you want to get. Also what do you mean by RAT?

Comment: RAT means "Right about there."

Comment: @RBlong2us and what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I believe it's editing vertex by vertex to get a certain look.

Comment: Correct. In origami, it means basically making irreproduceable results. In blender, technically any result is reproduceable, but in this case I mean doing one vertex at a time, because the tools cannot do it, in turn because there is no guideline or main logic to use. RAT folds are because of the same reason, although the process logic admittedly works slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

I've got something, though a bit tedious, that worked :D

Did not screenshoot the process, but it's fairly straightforward.

- Make each membrane area into a face (necessarily creating an edge between the tips of the spines.
- Wireframe the resulting mesh, deleting the original (can use modifier, but must apply after setting up).
- Delete all top and bottom bars of the resulted wireframe (meaning deleting horizontal edges, basically). What is left will be spines with edge-only ends.
- Create edges and faces as needed to manifold-ize the spines.
- For every pair of spines (1-2, 2-3, 3-4, etc):
  -- Select the faces on the sides of the two spines that face eachother.
  -- Use "Inset Faces" to create the area where the membrane will join onto the spine.
  -- Switch to vertex selection mode, and select less.
  -- Delete the selected vertices. The area for membrane joining is now open.
  -- Select both spines entirely, and then "Select Boundary Loop." The ring around the membrane joining place should be selected.
  -- "Bridge Edge Loops," bumping up the number of cuts to that of a low-poly mesh, setting the Interpolation to "Linear," and the profile shape to "Sphere," turning down the profile factor to create the pulled in effect. The pair of spines are now connected and re-manifold-ed.
  -- Select "Boundary Loop" again and "Mark Sharp" for shading purposes.
- Continue for each spine pair.
- Select the bottom of the mesh, and scale it along the Z axis to zero. Potentially make additional adjustments to the membrane, working to make it smooth, between any spines that did not have the same number of vertices as the ones they are connected to.
- Mark the edges surrounding the bottom as sharp.
- Shade the mesh as smooth.
- Add a subdivision surface modifier to the mesh.
- Use vertex painting to mark the spines as white, and the membranes as black.
- Use that vertex coloring to control the shaders as neccesary.

[image: Completed process PTL!]

PTL :)